# Could not get AWS load balancer details using get_all_load_balancers in boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm trying to get the load balancers which are created inside AWS.

Below is my code

```
    elb_conn = boto.ec2.elb.connect_to_region(aws_access_key_id=AWSaccesskey, aws_secret_access_key=AWSsecretkey, region_name='us-east-1')
    elb_conn.get_all_load_balancers(['loadbalancername'])[0]
```

I'me getting the error as

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Praload.py", line 17, in <module>
        elb_conn.get_all_load_balancers(['loadbalancer1'])[0]
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/elb/__init__.py", line 134, in get_all_load_balancers
        [('member', LoadBalancer)])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1186, in get_list
        raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
    boto.exception.BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request
    <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-06-01/">
      <Error>
        <Type>Sender</Type>
        <Code>LoadBalancerNotFound</Code>
        <Message>There is no ACTIVE Load Balancer named 'loadbalancername'</Message>
      </Error>
      <RequestId>131d2934-5bf6-11e7-92f6-17b72cd6bdf7</RequestId>
    </ErrorResponse>
```

boto version = 2.47.0

python version = 2.7

Comment: Why don't you call `get_all_load_balancers` with no parameters and see what you are getting and then call `get_all_load_balancers` with an existing loadbalancer.

Comment: I've tried calling the get_all_load_balancers with no parameters but it just gives me an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is kind of old but the error message I think is relevant for the current times.
You have to take into account the different kinds of elb that you might be having in order to use one client or another.
aws elb is for classic load balancers but the error message looks like to point out that the load balancer you are trying to get its **application, network, or gateway load balancer** so I will go with elbv2 over boto3, something like this:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('elbv2', aws_access_key_id=AWSaccesskey, aws_secret_access_key=AWSsecretkey, region_name='us-east-1')
lbs = client.describe_load_balancers(Names=['loadbalancernamehere'])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of ELBs: **Classic** and **V2**

You can list them separately

```
import boto3

# Create clients for both types of ELBs
elb_client = boto3.client('elb', region_name='us-west-1')
elbV2_client = boto3.client('elbv2', region_name='us-west-1')



# Get a list of classic ELBs
elbs = elb_client.describe_load_balancers()['LoadBalancerDescriptions']
elbs_list = [elb['LoadBalancerName'] for elb in elbs]



# Get a list of V2 ELBs
elbsv2 = elb_client.describe_load_balancers()['LoadBalancers']
elbsv2_list = [elb['LoadBalancerArn'] for elb in elbsv2]
```